# verify rake task complete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash

- deploy script runs a couple `rake` tasks.
- sometimes the rake tasks fail silently.

with bash i would like to set a variable if the task is successful, then check for that variable later to either continue/exit the script.

something like:

```
precompile_success = false
...
rake assets:precompile && precompile_success = true

...

if [ !precompile_success ]; then
    exit
fi
```

how would i?

Comment: What is that would you like to do? Can you break it down? It is not quite clear

Comment: @Inian i have rephrased the question ^^

Comment: Are you worried about the syntaxes or you tried not working? just a couple of syntax fixes in your attempt should solve it, skip the space during assignment have it as `name=value` and add a space before the negation check `[ ! $precompile_success ]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no literal support for `boolean` `true` (or) `false` in `bash`, but can be handled as place-holders for `1` and `0` using [C-stlye arithmetic-expressions with `(())`](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/arithmetic_expressions.shtml)

Using only your code-snippet and re-writing it using arithmetic expressions.

```
precompile_success=0

rake assets:precompile && precompile_success=1
((!precompile_success)) && exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a test with a.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
precompile_success=false
(exit $1) && precompile_success=true

if [ "$precompile_success" = true ]; then
    echo OK
else 
    echo KO
fi
```

Test

```
$ ./a.sh 0
OK
$ ./a.sh 1
KO
```